# Calculations in SSRS

Tags: asp.net, reporting, reporting-services, formula

I have an SSRS Report. In which I have a table that has some rows. I want to calculate some things on the basis of these rows. See the sample table and things to be calculated:

[image]

Employment Period is calculated using `if( DayEmployed>730) then add 1 to count.` and `count` is the count of `Employment Periods greater than 2 Years`. How can I calculate this in SSRS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In summary:

- an employment period is 365 days, or 1 year.
- you want the employment period count to start incrementing *after* they have clocked up 2 years

Assumptions:

- If the employee has worked 730 days, the employment period is still 0
- If the employee has worked 731 days, the employment period is 1
- the employment period remains at 1 until the employee clocks up 1096 days, at which point employment period becomes 2

Probably the easiest way to do it is:

```
= IIf(DaysEmployed > 730, CEILING(DaysEmployed/365) - 1, 0)
```

I did up a quick test of this in Excel, and excusing any syntactical errors* in my statement it does what you want.

---

**Edit:**

Okay, what you need is a conditional aggregate:

```
=Sum( IIF(DaysEmployed > 730, 1, 0), "DSEmploymentSummary")
```

This will do a sum over the `DaysEmployed` field in the scope of the object called `DSEmploymentSummary` (which is your data bound to the table/tablix).

Alternatively, you could have a hidden calculated column which simply contains a `1` or `0` for each row depending on the `DaysEmployed` being over the threshold, and then do a normal `SUM` on that column.

<sub>* My reporting is rusty, and i didn't want to crank up a new dummy report to test it.</sub>

Comment: I think you got me wrong. Basically what I want is: there is a table in which there are multiple clients are there. I have to check for each row, if `Days Employed > 730`, I want to display the count of those rows having `Days Employed > 730`.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this formula for this purpose:

```
=FormatNumber((iif(Fields!DaysEmployed.Value > 730, Count(Fields!DaysEmployed.Value, "DSEmploymentSummary"), 0))/CountRows("DSEmploymentSummary"),2,0,-1,-1)
```

Comment: Ouch. Does this seriously return the correct figure, and you can never get a divide by zero error?

Comment: Actually what I had to do was, hide all controls on the report when there is 0 row count. Now I tested it on 0 rows, and everything was perfect. I was also thinking the same that there must be a divide by zero error. But nothing happened. Control gets hidden successfully.

Comment: Okay tell me, will there be any chance of problem using my solution? Should I use urs?

Comment: Ohh no, even if i use yours formula, i'll have to divide it by no. of rows. Because it is the requirement. Your fornula will be like: `=Sum( IIF(DaysEmployed > 730, 1, 0), "DSEmploymentSummary")
/CountRows("DSEmploymentSummary")`

Comment: @asma, this was info that was missing from your question..... but yes you will have to divide by the number of rows to get the percentage.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry for that. Actually what you answered was the first part and percentage was the second part. I, by mistake, pasted here the second formula and by luck, you saw it. Thanx anyway :)